# Excel VBA function - add "+" to every word in a cell with exception

Tags: excel, vba

I found a topic here with almost the same question. @KazimierzJawor posted a solution (sub). What I want to do is turn his solution into a Function that will work with a single value passed in:

```
Function AddPlus(word As String) As String
 Dim tmpWords As Variant
 Dim SkipWords As Variant
 SkipWords = Array("в", "от", "под", "над", "за", "перед")
 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
 Dim Final As String, boExclude As Boolean
 tmpWords = Split(word.Value, " ")
 For i = 0 To UBound(tmpWords)
  For j = 0 To UBound(SkipWords)
   If UCase(SkipWords(j)) = UCase(tmpWords(i)) Then
    boExclude = True
   Exit For
   End If
  Next j
  If boExclude = False Then
   Final = Final & "+" & tmpWords(i) & " "
  Else
   Final = Final & tmpWords(i) & " "
  End If
  boExclude = False
 Next i
word = Left(Final, Len(Final) - 1)
Final = ""
End Function
```

However this function throws an error "Invalid Qualifier" in line

```
tmpWords = Split(word.Value, " ")
```

I know this has to be very easy, but I'm very new to VBA and haven't figured out how to fix this. Maybe someone here can help me?

Comment: `word` is a string variable, it has no properties like `.value` so remove it.

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, just found it by myself. However the function returns empty value, not matter what "word" passed in (cyrillic). I cannot understand why, since it should work (well worked in another topic here)

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
Function AddPlus(word As String) As String
Dim tmpWords As Variant
 Dim SkipWords As Variant
 SkipWords = Array("в", "от", "под", "над", "за", "перед")
 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
 Dim Final As String, boExclude As Boolean
 tmpWords = Split(word, " ")
 Final = ""
 For i = 0 To UBound(tmpWords)
  For j = 0 To UBound(SkipWords)
   If UCase(SkipWords(j)) = UCase(tmpWords(i)) Then
    boExclude = True
   Exit For
   End If
  Next j
  If boExclude = False Then
   Final = Final & "+" & tmpWords(i) & " "
  Else
   Final = Final & tmpWords(i) & " "
  End If
  boExclude = False
 Next i
AddPlus = Left(Final, Len(Final) - 1)    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to work on your naming conventions.

- Word is misleading it's multiple words
- SkipWords is an array. I'm okay with this one but I prefer using ar as a prefix for an array.  arSkipWords
- Final is a key word in other languages.  Although acceptable it is misleading.  Result is a standard name for a variable that holds a function's final result.

In my version I replaced the  `For i Loop`  with a `For Each w` because I think it is easier to read.  I replaced the  `For j Loop`  with the Filter function because I think it's a cool function.  By setting the Filter compare option to vbTextCompare there is no need to use UCase.

```
Function AddPlus(words As String) As String
    Dim w As Variant
    Dim arSkipWords As Variant
    Dim result As String

    arSkipWords = Array("в", "от", "под", "над", "за", "перед")

    For Each w In Split(words, " ")
        If UBound(Filter(arSkipWords, w, True, vbTextCompare)) = -1 Then
            result = result & w & "+"
        End If
    Next
    AddPlus = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
End Function
```